# ListView Activity, dynamically insertion of list items

Tags: android

I am trying to insert list items dynamically into the list view. As list view is created and displayed on the screen now suppose i got one items from the server or some where, now i want to add this item in the same list view what i have displayed. How to do that ?? Is there any way to insert items dynamically in the displayed list view without creating the list agtain and again. And is there any way to change the status of list item, that means can we interact while it is displaying?? your's reply will be appreciated. Thnx in advance !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add whatever you want to the data structure (meaning the `List`) that is being used by your `Adapter` and then call `notifiyDataSetChanged()` on your `Adapter`

With a regular `ArrayAdapter` it would be something like:

```
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.row, myList);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
...
//make a bunch of changes to data
list.add(foo);
listView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I can provide a more complicated example with a `BaseAdapter` as well.

**EDIT**

I created a little sample because this question seems to be pretty common.

In my sample I did everything in one class, just to make it a bit easier to follow it all in one place.

In the end, it's very much a model-view-controller type situation. You can even run the actual project by cloning it from here: https://github.com/levinotik/Android-Frequently-Asked-Questions

The essence of it is this:

```
/**
 * This Activity answers the frequently asked question
 * of how to change items on the fly in a ListView.
 *
 * In my own project, some of the elements (inner classes, etc)
 * might be extracted into separate classes, but for clarity
 * purposes, I'm doing everything inline.
 *
 * The example here is very, very basic. But if you understand
 * the concept, it can scale to anything. You have complex
 * views bound to complex data wit complex conditions.
 * You could model a facebook user and update the ListView
 * based on changes to that user's data that's represented in
 * your model.
 */
public class DynamicListViewActivity extends Activity {

    MyCustomAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
        super.onCreate(state);
        ListView listView = new ListView(this);
        setContentView(listView);

        /**
         * Obviously, this will typically some from somewhere else,
         * as opposed to be creating manually, one by one.
         */

        ArrayList<MyObject> myListOfObjects = new ArrayList<MyObject>();

        MyObject object1 = new MyObject("I love Android", "ListViews are cool");
        myListOfObjects.add(object1);
        MyObject object2 = new MyObject("Broccoli is healthy", "Pizza tastes good");
        myListOfObjects.add(object2);
        MyObject object3 = new MyObject("bla bla bla", "random string");
        myListOfObjects.add(object3);

        //Instantiate your custom adapter and hand it your listOfObjects
        mAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this, myListOfObjects);
        listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        /**
         * Now you are free to do whatever the hell you want to your ListView.
         * You can add to the List, change an object in it, whatever.
         * Just let your Adapter know that that the data has changed so it
         * can refresh itself and the Views in the ListView.
         */

        /**Here's an example. Set object2's condition to true.
        If everyting worked right, then the background color
        of that row will change to blue
         Obviously you would do this based on some later event.
         */
        object2.setSomeCondition(true);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



    }


    /**
     *
     *  An Adapter is bridge between your data
     *  and the views that make up the ListView.
     *  You provide some data and the adapter
     *  helps to place them into the rows
     *  of the ListView.
     *
     *  Subclassing BaseAdapter gives you the most
     *  flexibility. You'll have to override some
     *  methods to get it working.
     */
    class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private List<MyObject> mObjects;
        private Context mContext;

        /**
         * Create a constructor that takes a List
         * of some Objects to use as the Adapter's
         * data
         */
        public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, List<MyObject> objects) {
            mObjects = objects;
            mContext = context;
        }

        /**
         * Tell the Adapter how many items are in your data.
         * Here, we can just return the size of mObjects!
         */
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mObjects.size();
        }

        /**
         * Tell your the Adapter how to get an
         * item as the specified position in the list.
         */
        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return mObjects.get(position);
        }

        /**
         * If you want the id of the item
         * to be something else, do something fancy here.
         * Rarely any need for that.
         */
        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        /**
         * Here's where the real work takes place.
         * Here you tell the Adapter what View to show
         * for the rows in the ListView.
         *
         * ListViews try to recycle views, so the "convertView"
         * is provided for you to reuse, but you need to check if
         * it's null before trying to reuse it.
         * @param position
         * @param convertView
         * @param parent
         * @return
         */
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            MyView view;
            if(convertView == null){
                view = new MyView(mContext);
            } else {
                view = (MyView) convertView;
            }
            /**Here's where we utilize the method we exposed
             in order to change the view based on the data
             So right before you return the View for the ListView
             to use, you just call that method.
             */
            view.configure(mObjects.get(position));

            return view;
        }
    }


    /**
     * Very simple layout to use in the ListView.
     * Just shows some text in the center of the View
     */
    public class MyView extends RelativeLayout {

        private TextView someText;

        public MyView(Context context) {
            super(context);

            LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.addRule(CENTER_IN_PARENT);
            someText = new TextView(context);
            someText.setTextSize(20);
            someText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            someText.setLayoutParams(params);
            addView(someText);
        }

        /**
         * Remember, your View is an regular object like any other.
         * You can add whatever methods you want and expose it to the world!
         * We have the method take a "MyObject" and do things to the View
         * based on it.
         */

        public void configure(MyObject object) {

            someText.setText(object.bar);
            //Check if the condition is true, if it is, set background of view to Blue.
            if(object.isSomeCondition()) {
                this.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            } else {  //You probably need this else, because when views are recycled, it may just use Blue even when the condition isn't true.
                this.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * This can be anything you want. Usually,
     * it's some object that makes sense according 
     * to your business logic/domain.
     *
     * I'm purposely keeping this class as simple
     * as possible to demonstrate the point. 
     */
    class MyObject {
        private String foo;
        private String bar;
        private boolean someCondition;


        public boolean isSomeCondition() {
            return someCondition;
        }


        MyObject(String foo, String bar) {
            this.foo = foo;
            this.bar = bar;
        }

        public void setSomeCondition(boolean b) {
            someCondition = b;
        }
    }

}
```

If you grasp the concept here, you should be able to adapt (no pun intended) this to ArrayAdapters, etc.

Comment: can u plz elaborate with sample code ?? It will be more helpful to me.

Comment: ok fine. Suppose some list view items(e.g contact list) is there, now while displaying i want to change the text color of particular list item assume online/offline status came from server side or from some where. How can i do that??

Comment: @Arfin, yea you're going to have use a BaseAdapter and override getView and right before you return the View, check the status and alter the View as needed.

Comment: thnx buddy, but i am new to android, if possible can you please elaborate with code that will be really very useful for me.

Comment: Actually the point is, how i will get the event or status inside ListActivity or ArrayAdapter class based on that i need to make some changes inside the list view while it is displaying (e.g as i said before i want to change the text color of one item based on status, "status" i will get from the server while list is displaying. status- i am taking as a long value.

Comment: @Arfin, spent some time creating a sample for you and others.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by using an adapter, you fill in the ListView, update items whenever needed, add new items, etc.

If you're pulling data over the net, you can start by using a plain `ArrayAdapter` (usually by subclassing and overriding the `getView()` method to build your layout) and then adding and removing items from the list it provides. If you add items to the list, they will appear at the end of list when you scroll down (or immediately if you are at the bottom). If you modify an item, the list will immediately update on screen.

If you use a setter on the model objects, the adapter won't know about that, but you can call `notifyDataSetChanged()`. You will probably also want to look at the `setNotifyOnChange()` method in case you want to make several changes to the list at once without causing flicker on the screen.

Comment: can u plz elaborate with sample code ?? It will be more helpful to me.

Comment: It looks like @LuxuryMode has already created a detailed code example.

Answer (score 0):

use [notifyDataSetChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) method.